# How to parse HTML tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

I am trying to parse HTML page using HTML agility pack. My problem is, I have to parse and display page view count in each page using HAP. Suppose I have 3 pages.
Each page contains number of page views in a div or span or table at random positions.  Frankly, it do not have any fixed position and its difficult to find where is tag containing page views.

For example,

```
In Page 1
<!--Some content-->
<div>12 Page views</div>
<!--Some content-->

In Page 2
<!--Some content-->
<span>11 Page views</span>
<!--Some content-->

In Page 3
<!--Some content-->
<table><tr><td><!--Some content--></td></tr>
<tr><td>3 Page views only</td></tr></table>
<!--Some content-->
```

I need to find the count from the tags above. The format can be anything like,

```
<no> Page views
<no> Page views Only
<no> Page view till now
etc...
```

Can anybody suggest a way to parse the content?

Comment: maybe you should use regular expression: "[0-9]+ Page view[s]?( Only| till now){0,1}" or something similar? and verfify taht this is not part of your content...

Comment: The text in <no> tag is standard? meaning it will remain like "Page views" "Page views Only" etc.

Comment: Why WPF tag is added to this question?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @astreal I will try using regx.

Comment: @ebad86 Thanks for the comment . Text can vary because its another online site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for the problem. Its not a global solution but its working for me now. Hope it may help others.

```
int result = -1;
            var matches = Regex.Matches(
                HTMLText,
                @"(?:\S+\s)?\S*page views\S*(?:\s\S+)?",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
            );

            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                string val = m.Value;
                int res=-1;
                if (Int32.TryParse(val, out res))
                {
                    result = res;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you try to assign a particular Id or class to tag in which you are storing the "Page Views", then you can fetch that Id/class and retrieve its text.

Comment: @ebad86 thanks for the comment. The content is coming from an external site and I have no access to it. I am trying to read the content provided by that site.